# Extract data from file name and store it in a table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have different types of files (pdf, csv, doc, txt) in a directory.

Name of the files are something like this:

```
John.Doe.19900101.TX.pdf         //FirstName.LastName.DOB.StateOfResidence  
Bruce.Banner.19700101.PA.doc     
Steve.Rodgers.19760101.AR.csv    
Tony.Stark.19901210.CA.txt
```

How to write a stored procedure in Oracle to read the files in a directory and extract `FirstName, LastName, DOB, State`  and store it in a table in appropriate columns?

Ex: For the file `John.Doe.19900101.TX.pdf`, data should be extracted like this:

```
John in FirstName column  
Doe in LastName column   
19900101 in DOB column  
TX in State column  
whole file in CLOB column
```

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on, reading the directory list, or splitting the file names up into their constituent parts? How far have you got - it would be helpful to include the code you have so far, and why it isn't doing what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to work at the OS level to gather filenames from OS directory. Considering you are trying to get the information from Unix flavors; Following URL will help you grab the file listing into a table and even a view.

Code that you need is :

```
--drop directory SCRIPT_TEMP_DIR;

CREATE DIRECTORY SCRIPT_TEMP_DIR AS '/home/oracle/oracle_scripts'
;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DIRECTORY SCRIPT_TEMP_DIR TO USER_NAME
;  -- Here USER_NAME will be your SCHEMA/USER NAME

drop table USER_NAME.home_directory purge;

CREATE TABLE USER_NAME.home_directory
(
 filerecord VARCHAR2(15),
 flink VARCHAR2(2),
 fowner VARCHAR2(6),
 fgroup VARCHAR2(8),
 fsize VARCHAR2(32),
 fdate_part1 VARCHAR2(16),
 fdate_part2 VARCHAR2(16),
 fdate_year_or_time VARCHAR2(16),
 fname VARCHAR2(255)
)
 ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
 (
 TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY SCRIPT_TEMP_DIR
 ACCESS PARAMETERS
 (
 records delimited by newline
 preprocessor SCRIPT_TEMP_DIR:'listing.sh'
 fields terminated by whitespace
 (
 filerecord ,
 flink ,
 fowner ,
 fgroup ,
 fsize ,
 fdate_part1 ,
 fdate_part2 ,
 fdate_year_or_time ,
 fname 
 )
 )
 LOCATION ('listing.sh')
 )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Once this is done, you just need to select from above table created.

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_NAME.home_directory;
```

Later you can apply substr/instr functions to split info. You may also use regex function to get the requried information.

```
SELECT fname, 
    regexp_substr(fname, '[^.]+', 1, 1) part1, 
    regexp_substr(fname, '[^.]+', 1, 2) part2,
    regexp_substr(fname, '[^.]+', 1, 3) part3
  FROM USER_NAME.home_directory;
```

And this gives you :

[image]

The required URL to follow is [here](https://oraclefrontovik.com/2013/08/06/listing-files-from-a-linux-directory-from-within-oracle-sql-or-plsql-in-11g/)
The code pasted above was modified where you need to change USER_NAME as well while granting permissions on directory.

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning that this directory is not OS directory. I've the path to directory and I need to read the file names, extract the values from file name, store those extracted values in an existing table along with the actual file in a CLOB column.

Comment: and the regexp_substr() is working as expected. But, how can I loop it with all the files in the directory irrespective of the file type?

Comment: @intruder : If you follow the code above. It is giving you all the file names in the external table which is created as a result of CREATE TABLE command. Later when you run the Query which is selecting data from HOME_DIRECTORY table above, it gives you file names seperated into multiple columns. You may adjust your query and contatinate your results. Something like 

SELECT FILENAME_PART1 || ' ' || FILENAME_PART3 || ' ' || FILENAME_PART4 
FROM HOME_DIRECTORY;

Dont forget to mark my answer as the right answer, since it gives you the complete solution :)